# Python: Heroku crashes on running instapy

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, heroku, instapy

I am making a instagram bot for my website using python , selenium and instapy. I have never made something like that with Python.

I have installed chrome buildpack and chrome driver in heroku.I read that Instapy has removed the chrome support due to the fact that chrome detects bots frequently.

It shows me Following Error. [image: error link.]

Bot.py

```
import os
from instapy import InstaPy
from instapy import smart_run

insta_username = os.environ['INSTA_USER']
insta_password = os.environ['INSTA_PASSWORD']

# get a session!
session = InstaPy(
username=insta_username,
password=insta_password,
headless_browser=True,
)
# let's go! :
with smart_run(session):
# general settings
session.set_relationship_bounds(
    enabled=True,
    potency_ratio=None,
    delimit_by_numbers=True,
    max_followers=6000,
    max_following=3000,
    min_followers=30,
    min_following=30)
session.set_user_interact(
    amount=2, randomize=True, percentage=30, media='Photo')
session.set_do_like(enabled=True, percentage=100)
session.set_do_comment(enabled=True, percentage=5)
session.set_comments([
    'Nice shot! @{}', 'I love your profile! @{}', '@{} Love it!',
    '@{} :heart::heart:', 'Love your posts @{}', 'Looks awesome @{}',
    'Getting inspired by you @{}', ':raised_hands: Yes!',
    '@{}:revolving_hearts::revolving_hearts:', '@{}:fire::fire::fire:',
    'Your feed is an inspiration :thumbsup:',
    'Just incredible :open_mouth:', 'What camera did you use @{}?',
    'Love your posts @{}', 'Looks awesome @{}',
    'Getting inspired by you @{}', ':raised_hands: Yes!',
    'I can feel your passion @{} :muscle:'
],
    media='Photo')

# unfollow activity
session.unfollow_users(
    amount=126,
    nonFollowers=True,
    style="RANDOM",
    unfollow_after=42 * 60 * 60,
    sleep_delay=300)

# follow activity
amount_number = 500
session.follow_user_followers(['chrisburkard', 'danielkordan'],
                              amount=amount_number,
                              randomize=False,
                              interact=True,
                              sleep_delay=240)
""" Joining Engagement Pods...
    """
session.join_pods(topic='general', engagement_mode='no_comments')
```

Selenium.py

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from instapy_chromedriver import binary_path
 import os

 browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=binary_path)
 browser.implicitly_wait(5)

 browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
 login_link = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Log In')]")


 username_input = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='username']")
 password_input = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='password']")

 username_input.send_keys("<your username>")
 password_input.send_keys("<your password>")
 login_link.click()
 sleep(2)

 login_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']")
 login_button.click()
 sleep(5)
 browser.close()
```

Procfile

```
  web: python3 instabot.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the version of python in runtime.txt file to 3.9.1 and you may try manually downloading the geckodriver and pushing them to your heroku app via cli....and geckodriver is only for firefox.... modify your program for firefox

Comment: can you explain it briefly. I am new to heroku cli and didn't  get the answer. Pardon for wasting your time.

Comment: you may refer this site. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python

Comment: you will get an idea,that how things work in heroku